# pdf.getPage is not a function when trying to use pdf.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, pdf.js, pdfjs-dist

I want to extract all text (using node and pdfjs) from a given PDF file, so I installed `pdfjs-dist` and tried with this code:

```
import pdfjs from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js';
import pdfjsWorker from 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry.js';

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;

const pdf = await pdfjs.getDocument('testdoc.pdf');
const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
```

However that gives me

```
const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
                       ^

TypeError: pdf.getPage is not a function
```

Why is that and how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `.promise` to the end of your `.getDocument()` call to expose the Promises API.

```js
const pdf = await pdfjs.getDocument('testdoc.pdf').promise;
const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
```

Source: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/